# Weblate trouble with merge conflict

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, weblate

I'm a junior web dev.
I'm working on a project translation.
We use weblate linked with a gitlab repo.
I worked on some stuff in the "test-localisation-back" branch.
Then i pushed on same remote branch
When weblate tried to automatically merge, he failed and then this message appeared :
"The translation was automatically locked due to following alerts: Could not merge the repository."
I tried to push, pull or rebase but it didn't went well with message :
"Could not merge remote branch into Poplab - Backend/API."(weblate component name)

Locally my branch is up to date with repo

There is this message on weblate repo details :
On branch test-localisation-weblate
Your branch and 'origin/test-localisation-weblate' have diverged,
and have 2 and 4281 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

I'm not sure what to do. I'm scared about doing a reset or cleanup
[weblate repo admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV541.png)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried following the [documentation](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-fix-merge-conflicts-in-translations)?

Comment: Yes i checked but i didn't found weblate command line interface...

Comment: Ok fine i achieved this. Ty for answers.